# Why can't I make an API request from Oracle?

Tags: oracle, http, https, request

I developed the following Oracle procedure in order to use an API mounted on a subdomain of the company where I work. This API works properly with POSTMAN tests, using the POST method and sending a JSON like the following:

```
{
    "student_id": "15",
    "created_by": "1"
}
```

My procedure:

```
PROCEDURE create_bb_user (
    student_id IN NUMBER,
    created_by IN NUMBER
) IS
    req     utl_http.req;
    res     utl_http.resp;
    url     VARCHAR2(4000) := 'https://...';
    name    VARCHAR2(4000);
    buffer  CLOB;
    content CLOB := '{"student_id":"'
                    || student_id
                    || '", "created_by":"'
                    || created_by
                    || '"}';
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line(content);
    req := utl_http.begin_request(url, 'POST', ' HTTP/1.1');
    utl_http.set_header(req, 'user-agent', 'mozilla/4.0');
    utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Type', 'application/json');
    utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Length', length(content));
    utl_http.write_text(req, content);
    dbms_output.put_line('buffer1');
    res := utl_http.get_response(req);
    dbms_output.put_line('buffer2');
    BEGIN
        LOOP
            utl_http.read_line(res, buffer);
            dbms_output.put_line(buffer);
        END LOOP;

        utl_http.end_response(res);
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN utl_http.end_of_body THEN
            utl_http.end_response(res);
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            utl_http.end_response(res);
    END;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        utl_http.end_response(res);
END;
```

I simply call it as follows:

```
BEGIN
    PKG_LC_CALL_APIS.CREATE_BB_USER (15, 1);
END
```

However, I receive the following errors:

> Error report -
>
> - ORA-29273: HTTP request failure
> - ORA-06512: in "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1527
> - ORA-29261: wrong argument
> - ORA-06512: in "SCE.PKG_LC_CALL_APIS", line 215
> - ORA-29273: HTTP request failure
> - ORA-06512: in "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130
> - ORA-28860: Fatal SSL error
> - ORA-06512: on line 2
> - 00000 - "HTTP request failed".
> - *Cause: The UTL_HTTP package failed to execute the HTTP request.
> - *Action: Use get_detailed_sqlerrm to check the detailed error message. Fix the error and retry the HTTP request.

Do I need to make an additional configuration? It should be clarified that I have already generated the access list that outputs the DB to the server where the API is.

Comment: `Action: Use get_detailed_sqlerrm to check the detailed error message.` Providing this info would be helpful.

Comment: also confirm you defined an ACL rule to allow for this http outbound request, but yeah, grab the detailed error message stack as indicated in the Action field

Comment: Using the query «SELECT utl_http.get_detailed_sqlerrm FROM dual;» I got the next message: "ORA-29261: bad argument
ORA-29273: HTTP request failure
ORA-06512: in "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130
ORA-28860: Error SSL fatal"

Comment: sounds like a cert issue for HTTPS requests

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Yes, that was it, thank you. I had to make it not redirect directly by https.